# Download a custom dataset in Azure ML Jupyter/iPython Notebook using R

Tags: r, azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I need to download a custom dataset in an Azure Jupyter/iPython Notebook.
My ultimate goal is to install an R package. To be able to do this the package (the dataset) needs to be downloaded in code. I followed the steps outlined by Andrie de Vries in the comments section of this post: [Jupyter Notebooks with R in Azure ML Studio](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2016/03/30/jupyter-notebooks-with-r-in-azure-ml-studio-2/#comments).

Uploading the package as a ZIP file was without problems, but when I run the code in my notebook I get an error:

> Error in curl(x$DownloadLocation, handle = h, open = conn): Failure
>   when receiving data from the peer Traceback:
>
> 1. download.datasets(ws, "plotly_3.6.0.tar.gz.zip")
> 2. lapply(1:nrow(datasets), function(j) get_dataset(datasets[j,   .     ], ...))
> 3. FUN(1L[[1L]], ...)
> 4. get_dataset(datasets[j, ], ...)
> 5. curl(x$DownloadLocation, handle = h, open = conn)

So I simplified my code into:

```
library("AzureML")
ws <- workspace()
ds <- datasets(ws)
ds$Name

data <- download.datasets(ws, "plotly_3.6.0.tar.gz.zip")
head(data)
```

Where "plotly_3.6.0.tar.gz.zip" is the name of my dataset of data type "Zip".
Unfortunately this results in the same error.
To rule out data type issues I also tried to download another dataset of mine which is of data type "Dataset". Also the same error.

Now I change the dataset I want to download to one of the sample datasets of AzureML Studio.
"text.preprocessing.zip" is of datatype Zip

```
data <- download.datasets(ws, "text.preprocessing.zip")
```

"Flight Delays Data" is of datatype GenericCSV

```
data <- download.datasets(ws, "Flight Delays Data")
```

Both of the sample datasets can be downloaded without problems.

**So why can't I download my own saved dataset?**

I could not find anything helpful in the documentation of the download.datasets function. Not on [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AzureML/versions/0.2.10/topics/download.datasets?), nor on [cran.r-project.org (page 17-18)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureML/AzureML.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error I got was due to a bug in the (then early) Azure ML Studio.

I tried again after the reply of [Daniel Prager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572285/3319439) only to find out my code works as expected without any changes. Adding the `id` and `auth` parameters was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(AzureML)
ws <- workspace(
id = "your AzureML ID",
auth = "your AzureML Key"
)
name <- "Name of your saved data"
ws <- workspace()
```